# Can't compile any of three Gegl versions (and one babl)

Tags: compiling, make

I have been trying to compile to Gegl versions. The first one is the 0.2.0:

When I try to compile it with make, I receive

> make[4]: Entering directory `/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/gegl-0.2.0/docs/gallery'
>   --[Updating sample compositions]--
>   ./clones.xml
>
> (lt-gegl:7949): GEGL-gegl-node.c-WARNING **: Failed to set operation type gegl:text, using a passthrough op instead
>
> (lt-gegl:7949): GEGL-gegl-extension-handler.c-WARNING **: No loader for extension ".jpg", falling back to "gegl:magick-load"
>
> (lt-gegl:7949): GEGL-gegl-node.c-WARNING **: Failed to set operation type gegl:png-load, using a passthrough op instead
>
> (lt-gegl:7949): GEGL-gegl-c.c-WARNING **: gegl_node:GeglChantnop_c has no property named: 'path'
>   /bin/bash: line 1:  7949 Segmentation fault      GEGL_DEBUG_TIME=yes GEGL_SWAP=RAM GEGL_PATH=../../operations ../../bin/gegl clones.xml -o `echo clones.png | sed s?./??` > `echo clones.png | sed s?./?? | sed -e s/png/txt/`
>   make[5]: *** [clones.png] Error 139
>   ./OpenRaster-00.xml
>
> (lt-gegl:7978): GEGL-gegl-node.c-WARNING **: Failed to set operation type gegl:text, using a passthrough op instead
>
> (lt-gegl:7978): GEGL-gegl-extension-handler.c-WARNING **: No loader for extension ".jpg", falling back to "gegl:magick-load"
>
> (lt-gegl:7978): GEGL-gegl-node.c-WARNING **: Failed to set operation type gegl:png-load, using a passthrough op instead
>
> (lt-gegl:7978): GEGL-gegl-c.c-WARNING **: gegl_node:GeglChantnop_c has no property named: 'path'
>   /bin/bash: line 1:  7978 Segmentation fault      GEGL_DEBUG_TIME=yes GEGL_SWAP=RAM GEGL_PATH=../../operations ../../bin/gegl OpenRaster-00.xml -o `echo OpenRaster-00.png | sed s?./??` > `echo OpenRaster-00.png | sed s?./?? | sed -e s/png/txt/`
>   make[5]: *** [OpenRaster-00.png] Error 139
>   ./OpenRaster-01.xml
>
> (lt-gegl:8006): GEGL-gegl-node.c-WARNING **: Failed to set operation type gegl:text, using a passthrough op instead
>
> (lt-gegl:8006): GEGL-gegl-extension-handler.c-WARNING **: No loader for extension ".png", falling back to "gegl:magick-load"
>
> (lt-gegl:8006): GEGL-gegl-node.c-WARNING **: Failed to set operation type gegl:png-load, using a passthrough op instead
>
> (lt-gegl:8006): GEGL-gegl-c.c-WARNING **: gegl_node:GeglChantnop_c has no property named: 'path'
>   /bin/bash: line 1:  8006 Segmentation fault      GEGL_DEBUG_TIME=yes GEGL_SWAP=RAM GEGL_PATH=../../operations ../../bin/gegl OpenRaster-01.xml -o `echo OpenRaster-01.png | sed s?./??` > `echo OpenRaster-01.png | sed s?./?? | sed -e s/png/txt/`
>   make[5]: *** [OpenRaster-01.png] Error 139
>   ./OpenRaster-04.xml
>
> (lt-gegl:8034): GEGL-gegl-node.c-WARNING **: Failed to set operation type gegl:text, using a passthrough op instead
>
> (lt-gegl:8034): GEGL-gegl-extension-handler.c-WARNING **: No loader for extension ".jpg", falling back to "gegl:magick-load"
>
> (lt-gegl:8034): GEGL-gegl-node.c-WARNING **: Failed to set operation type gegl:png-load, using a passthrough op instead
>
> (lt-gegl:8034): GEGL-gegl-c.c-WARNING **: gegl_node:GeglChantnop_c has no property named: 'path'
>   /bin/bash: line 1:  8034 Segmentation fault      GEGL_DEBUG_TIME=yes GEGL_SWAP=RAM GEGL_PATH=../../operations ../../bin/gegl OpenRaster-04.xml -o `echo OpenRaster-04.png | sed s?./??` > `echo OpenRaster-04.png | sed s?./?? | sed -e s/png/txt/`
>   make[5]:**  [OpenRaster-04.png] Error 139
>   make[4]:  **[images.stamp] Error 2
>   make[4]: Leaving directory `/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/gegl-0.2.0/docs/gallery'
>   make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
>   make[3]: Leaving directory`/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/gegl-0.2.0/docs/gallery'
>   make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
>   make[2]: Leaving directory `/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/gegl-0.2.0/docs'
>   make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
>   make[1]: Leaving directory`/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/gegl-0.2.0'
>   make: *** [all] Error 2

If I try the older Gegl-0.1.0 I receive

> make[2]: Entering directory `/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/gegl-0.1.0/bin'
>   /bin/bash ../libtool --mode=link gcc -pthread -I/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/Glib-2.28/include/glib-2.0 -I/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/Glib-2.28/lib/glib-2.0/include   -I/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/Babl-0.1.10/include/babl-0.1    -g -O2 -Wall -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wold-style-definition -mmmx -msse  ../gegl/libgegl-0.0.la -pthread -Wl,--export-dynamic -L/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/Glib-2.28/lib -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -lgthread-2.0 -lrt -lglib-2.0   -L/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/Babl-0.1.10/lib -lbabl-0.1 -lm      -o gegl  gegl.o gegl-options.o gegl-path-smooth.o
>
>   libtool: link: gcc -pthread -I/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/Glib-2.28/include/glib-2.0 -I/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/Glib-2.28/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/Babl-0.1.10/include/babl-0.1 -g -O2 -Wall -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wold-style-definition -mmmx -msse -pthread -Wl,--export-dynamic -o .libs/gegl gegl.o gegl-options.o gegl-path-smooth.o  ../gegl/.libs/libgegl-0.0.so -L/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/Glib-2.28/lib -L/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/Zlib-1.2.8//lib -L/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/Babl-0.1.10/lib /media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/Glib-2.28/lib/libgio-2.0.so -lresolv -lz /media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/Glib-2.28/lib/libgobject-2.0.so /media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/Glib-2.28/lib/libgmodule-2.0.so /media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/Glib-2.28/lib/libgthread-2.0.so -lpthread /media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/Glib-2.28/lib/libglib-2.0.so -lrt /media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/Babl-0.1.10/lib/libbabl-0.1.so -ldl -lm -pthread -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/Gegl-0.1.0/lib -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/Glib-2.28/lib -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/Babl-0.1.10/lib
>   ../gegl/.libs/libgegl-0.0.so: undefined reference to`babl_total_usecs'
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>   make[2]: *** [gegl] Error 1
>   make[2]: Leaving directory `/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/gegl-0.1.0/bin'
>   make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
>   make[1]: Leaving directory`/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/gegl-0.1.0'
>   make: *** [all] Error 2

If I try the latest Gegl-0.3.28, it complains during configure execution, of the lack of presence of Babl 0.1.42. Okay, I downloaded it, configured it. When I issue a make command I received:

> ake[4]: Entering directory `/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/babl-0.1.42/babl'
>     CC       libbabl_0.1_la-babl.lo
>     CC       libbabl_0.1_la-babl-cache.lo
>     CC       libbabl_0.1_la-babl-component.lo
>     CC       libbabl_0.1_la-babl-conversion.lo
>     CC       libbabl_0.1_la-babl-core.lo
>     CC       libbabl_0.1_la-babl-db.lo
>     CC       libbabl_0.1_la-babl-extension.lo
>     CC       libbabl_0.1_la-babl-fish-path.lo
>     CC       libbabl_0.1_la-babl-fish-reference.lo
>     CC       libbabl_0.1_la-babl-fish-simple.lo
>     CC       libbabl_0.1_la-babl-fish.lo
>     CC       libbabl_0.1_la-babl-format.lo
>     CC       libbabl_0.1_la-babl-hash-table.lo
>     CC       libbabl_0.1_la-babl-icc.lo
>   babl-icc.c:1029: error: redefinition of typedef ‘UTF32’
>   babl-icc.c:613: note: previous declaration of ‘UTF32’ was here
>   babl-icc.c:1030: error: redefinition of typedef ‘UTF16’
>   babl-icc.c:614: note: previous declaration of ‘UTF16’ was here
>   babl-icc.c:1031: error: redefinition of typedef ‘UTF8’
>   babl-icc.c:615: note: previous declaration of ‘UTF8’ was here
>   make[4]: *** [libbabl_0.1_la-babl-icc.lo] Error 1
>   make[4]: Leaving directory`/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/babl-0.1.42/babl'
>   make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
>   make[3]: Leaving directory `/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/babl-0.1.42/babl'
>   make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
>   make[2]: Leaving directory`/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/babl-0.1.42/babl'
>   make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
>   make[1]: Leaving directory `/media/34GB/Arquivos-de-Programas-Linux/babl-0.1.42'
>   make: *** [all] Error 2

So I can't compile any of the three versions. Two for direct reasons, one indirectly. The babl seems to be something about conflicting definitions of declared things in different header files. But how I solve it?

The gegl 0.2 problem seems to be related to png and xml. I thought about disabling libpng support at the configure but I will need it in the future (probably).

The gegl 0.1.0 seems not able to find something in a babl's library, but how I solve it?

I would appreciate suggestions to solve any of these problems.

Comment: `gegl-0.2.0` compiles OK (gcc/g++ 7.3.0) with babl-0.1.42 and libpng-1.2.59 . .... ....`gegl-0.1.0` (year 2009): Use old gcc/g++(3.4.6 .. 4.1.2) ... and an older `babl` : 0.1.0 (2009)

Comment: Well, I cannot compile babl 0.1.42. I am using gcc 4.4.3.  I am thinking of trying to compile a gcc 3.4.6 and then try to compile babl 0.1.0. What do you think?

Comment: ? Which OS are you using ?

Comment: Ubuntu 10.04. And in case you ask, I cannot move to a newer distribution without solving this issue, except through dvd booting, which is little practical  (And at the moment I do not want to do it anyway, but certainly will sometime in the future)

Comment: @Knud Larsen. Are you still there? Did you saw my last comment? Anyway I am ready to download and try to compile gcc 3.4.6 but would like to hear if you think it's a good idea.

Comment: **Ubuntu 10.04** : Why not use the default extra compiler  gcc-4.1 / g++-4.1 ? .... → `sudo apt-get install g++-4.1` .... ( gcc-3.4-6 cannot usually be compiled with a much later compiler.)